# toggle class with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have the following jquery code to toggle class :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $(".button").click(function(){
       $("#wrapper-container").toggleClass('open-close');
    });
});
```

Can anyone please convert this code in pure JavaScript so that it can run with jQuery library file.
Update: Clicking element don't have an id so the other example is not working.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880890/how-do-i-toggle-an-elements-class-in-pure-javascript

Comment: @DFayet how can we do it without ID's

Comment: the answers of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880890/how-do-i-toggle-an-elements-class-in-pure-javascript) don't use ID