# Add/Remove class when clicking on element with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

With a for loop, I removed the active class inside the `a` tag. However, when I want to add a class when clicking nothing happens and the class gets added to the `li` and `a` tag but without the active class name.

This has been asked so many times but I still cannot figure it out. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/fu5e7946/

Comment: Have you tried `element.classList.toggle('active-list')`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I add and remove an active class to an element in pure JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38990163/how-can-i-add-and-remove-an-active-class-to-an-element-in-pure-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you are looping within your loop twice. I have fixed that.
You simply need to remove the previous active class and add new one like this:

```
  document.querySelector(".sidenav a.active-list").classList.remove("active-list");
    e.target.classList.add('active-list');
```

You can this: **codepen:link**  https://codepen.io/emmeiWhite/pen/jOMZRxd

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('div, ul, li, a');

elements.forEach(i => {
  i.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    document.querySelector(".sidenav a.active-list").classList.remove("active-list");
    e.target.classList.add('active-list');
    
  });
});
```

```css
.sidenav {
  width: 130px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 20px;
  left: 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sidenav ul {
  background-color: black;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.sidenav > ul > li {
  color: white;
  margin: 0px;
}

.sidenav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 4em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: grey;
}

.sidenav .active-list {
  background-color: #e2c9be;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
   <div id="active-buttons" class="sidenav" style="padding-top: 100px;">
          <ul class="text-center">
            <li>
              <a href="#Profile" class="active-list">Profile</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#Experience">Experience</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#Projects">Projects</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#Skills">Skills</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with `toggle` (more info: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)). There you have working example:

```js
let elements = document.querySelectorAll('div, ul, li, a');

elements.forEach(i => {
  i.addEventListener('click', function() {
    i.classList.toggle('active-list');
  });
});
```

```css
.sidenav {
  width: 130px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 20px;
  left: 10px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sidenav ul {
  background-color: black;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
  padding-right: 0px;
}

.sidenav > ul > li {
  color: white;
  margin: 0px;
}

.sidenav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  display: block;
  line-height: 4em;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: grey;
}

div ul li a.active-list {
  background-color: #e2c9be;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="active-buttons" class="sidenav" style="padding-top: 100px;">
  <ul class="text-center">
   <li>
    <a href="#Profile" class="active-list">Profile</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#Experience">Experience</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#Projects">Projects</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#Skills">Skills</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Comment: Hi Bro @cccn. There is one small issue with this approach. If you click on the already active element. It is also toggled which should not happed. If clicked on the current active element it should be active.. :)

Comment: @ImranRafiqRather yeah, true. I missed that in understanding the task