# Add a class to a specific dom outside of Component in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a component that opens up a modal based on if the a variable called 'isVisible' is True or False. Once the modal is visible, I would like to add a class to the 'body' tag of the page and once it is closed, I'd like to remove the class from the 'body' tag.

Below is a snippet of my code and what I have tried.

```
import {Component, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'modal',
    template: '<div class="modal_div">
        <div (click)="closeCard()"></div>
        <div class="modal_body">blah</div>
    </div>'
})

export class DailogComponent{
    isVisible: boolean;
    constructor(public element: ElementRef){
        this.isVisible = false;
    }

    OpenModal(){
        this.isVisible = true;
        //add css class to body here which is where I am lost 
       console.log(this.element.nativeElement.parentNode.querySelector('body'));
    }

    closeModal(){
        this.isVisible = false;
        //remove css class to body here which is where I am lost 
       console.log(this.element.nativeElement.parentNode.querySelector('body'));
    }
}
```

Comment: Tell me if my answer is what you were waiting for. This is a bizarre question as you have already the knowledge necessary to find it yourself. Or maybe my answer is just plain wrong in which case I'll learn something myself.

Answer (score 1):

Someone correct me if this is wrong or an anti pattern in ng.

You can just use javascript for that. If I understood correctly you want to change the class of the body tag. So the body of the page. `<body></body>`

[How do I toggle an element's class in pure JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880890/how-do-i-toggle-an-elements-class-in-pure-javascript)

and [getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) or yeah query selector as you did, I personally use getElementsByTagName for no good reason other than I'm used to it.

```
  //don't capitalize function names.
  toggleBodyClass(){
    this.toggleClass(document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0], 'myclass');
  }
  //this function is taken from the Stackoverflow thread posted above.
  toggleClass(ele, class1) {
    let classes = ele.className;
    let regex = new RegExp('\\b' + class1 + '\\b');
    let hasOne = classes.match(regex);
    class1 = class1.replace(/\s+/g, '');
    if (hasOne)
      ele.className = classes.replace(regex, '');
    else
      ele.className = classes + class1;
  }
```

tested, works

Comment: Cheers mate. I was over thinking this and was only trying to solve through angular2. This makes for a straight and easy answer

Comment: @user875139 yeah, I'm glad this was what you were asking and I thought it was a very bizarre question as you had all the knowledge to do so already. Sometimes it's just that simple :p

Comment: yeah sometimes one just forgets the basics especially when picking up something new. (Angular2 in my case lol)