# Why my Javascript code working only in the console?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that supposed to do a toggle after a click,

but this line of code doesn't do the job after first click.

`var toggle = document.querySelector('header nav ul').className = (toggle) ? '' : 'open';`

- only if i execute it in the console it works..

Plunker:
https://embed.plnkr.co/B5iFwB/

[image]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880890/how-do-i-toggle-an-elements-class-in-pure-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var toggle` is inside a block that is not global, you need to write code like:

```
var toggle;
document.querySelector('.btn-menu').addEventListener('click', function(){
    toggle = document.querySelector('header nav ul').className = (toggle) ? '' : 'open';
});
```

Comment: No initial value of `toggle` is given, so `(toggle)` (in the ternary expression) will evaluate to `false`. This may or may not be desirable. The OP should set an initial value to prevent confusion by future programmers.

Comment: then just remove `var` from inside block

Comment: Note, any variable defined outside a function will make it global.

Answer (score 2):

You're seeing this behaviour because your code references a variable `toggle` which is declared in the same statement. It works in the console because by the time the expression is evaluated for the second time `toggle` now exists.

I can't suggest an improvement because I don't know how you expect the function to work, given you don't define an initial value for `toggle` before your statement evaluates.

Also, you're using jQuery, but using Vanilla.js code-style within your jQuery event-handler. You should change your code to be more consistent: either only use idiomtic jQuery or idiomatic Vanilla.js.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for `toggle`

You should check if `open` class is available on element, then remove it else add it. You can use `.classList.add` and `.classList.remove` to achieve this:

[Updated Code](https://plnkr.co/edit/B5iFwB?p=info)

#### Sample:

```js
document.querySelector('.btn-menu').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var nav = document.querySelector('header nav ul');
  if (nav.classList.contains('open'))
    nav.classList.remove('open')
  else
    nav.classList.add('open')
})
```

```css
body {
  margin-top: 80px;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
}

header .btn-menu{
  background: #e5e5e5;
  direction: rtl;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding-right: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

header nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #1b2125;
  height: 0;
}

header nav ul.open {
  height: auto;
}

header nav li a {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <div class="btn-menu">≡</div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">About</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="">Services</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your code it will do top to bottom toggle,

```
  $('.btn-menu').on('click',function(){
$('header nav ul').slideToggle( "slide" );
```

});

also you need to add JQuery to your code. Add this in your head

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```