# Changing the background color of a <tr> on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change the background color of a  element when it is clicked on. Basically, I want to be able to toggle this color back and forth each time it's clicked.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
        function activateButton1() {
            var x = document.getElementById('postButton1');

            if (x.className == 'postButton1') {
                x.className = 'postButton1on';
            } else {
                x.className = 'postButton1';
            }
        }
```

I'm using two different CSS classes that have different background colors, but it's not working. Can anyone offer any insight?

Comment: Could you show a working example with your HTML too. Presumably `x.classList.toggle('postButton1on')` should solve your problem if you arrange your CSS correctly

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I toggle an element's class in pure JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880890/how-do-i-toggle-an-elements-class-in-pure-javascript) and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195951/change-an-elements-class-with-javascript will also be much helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the `toggle` method:

```
function activateButton1() {
    this.classList.toggle("postButton1on");
}
```

You could even fire this in the html to simplify things:

```
<tr onclick="this.classList.toggle('postButton1on')">...</tr>
```

And then as long as the `.postButton1on` css is declared after the `.postButton1` css then the `.postButton1on` background color will overwrite what was set previously.

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery you can do it by

```
$( "#postButton1" ).on('click', function(){
  $( this ).toggleClass( "postButton1on" );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not be working because you might be mixing `id` and `class`, as they have the same name, at least in the JS you posted.
Here's everything packed in an HTML document, tested to work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    .off {
      background-color: white;
    }
    .on {
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function change() {
      var x = document.getElementById('post');
      if (x.className.match('on')) {
        x.className = 'off';
      } else {
        x.className = 'on';
      }
    }
    function change2() {
      var x = document.getElementById('row');
      if (x.className.match('on')) {
        x.className = 'off';
      } else {
        x.className = 'on';
      }
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="post" onclick="change()" class="on">hello</button>
  <table>
    <tr id="row" onclick="change2()" class="on">
      <td>hey</td>
      <td>hey</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```