# Add class by clicking and remove it at the next click

Tags: javascript

I built an app which add a class when i click on specified element. I want to add an additional functionality to my app. When i will click on an item i want to add my class `clicked` ( now the app works in the same way), but when i will click on another item i want to add the class on the last item and to remove the class from the first item.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const list = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            const curentItem = e.target;
            if (curentItem) {
                curentItem.classList.add('clicked');
                console.log(curentItem)
            }

        })
    }
});
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const mapping = arr.map(item => `<li class="item">${item}</li>`);
document.querySelector('.items').innerHTML = mapping.join(' ');
```

```css
.clicked {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <ul class="items">
  </ul>
</div>
```

How to change my code to get the specified result?

Comment: So basically you only want one element to have the 'clicked' class at any given time, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I toggle an element's class in pure JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880890/how-do-i-toggle-an-elements-class-in-pure-javascript)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can loop through list and remove class from each item and then add to the last item

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const list = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            const curentItem = e.target;
            if (curentItem) {
                list.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('clicked'))
                curentItem.classList.add('clicked');
                console.log(curentItem)
            }

        })
    }
});
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const mapping = arr.map(item => `<li class="item">${item}</li>`);
document.querySelector('.items').innerHTML = mapping.join(' ');
```

```css
.clicked {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <ul class="items">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Further more you shouldn't create html element using `innerHTML` and after that use
`querySelectorAll()` and select the elements.

A better and clean way for same functionality is like.

```js
const ul = document.querySelector('.items');
const listItems = [];
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  initalizeItems([1, 2, 3, 4])
});

function initalizeItems(items){
  items.forEach(text => {
    const li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = text;
    li.addEventListener('click', onItemClick) 
    listItems.push(li);
    ul.appendChild(li)
  })
}

function onItemClick(){
  listItems.forEach(item => item.classList.remove('clicked'));
  this.classList.add('clicked');
}
```

```css
.clicked {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <ul class="items">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use `classList.toggle` instead of `classList.remove` then  `classList.add`?

Comment: @connexo I don't think it will work here. How can we use it here?

Comment: @connexo Oh yeah its nice. I didn't knew about the second parameter. But I would still go with my way because its kind of a simple I guess

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the class white looping all items inside the click event listner :

```
.....
for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    list[i].classList.remove('clicked');
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    const list = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
    for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
        list[i].addEventListener('click', function (e) {
            for (let i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
              list[i].classList.remove('clicked');
            // querySelectorAll return an array of dom elements, u can access them directly.
            }
            const curentItem = e.target;
            if (curentItem){
                curentItem.classList.add('clicked');
                console.log(curentItem)
            }

        })
    }
});
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const mapping = arr.map(item => `<li class="item">${item}</li>`);
document.querySelector('.items').innerHTML = mapping.join(' ');
```

```css
.clicked {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <ul class="items">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: this won't work when clicking on the element, cuz it is only executed on DOMContentLoaded

Comment: @M0ns1f Sow how do you explain that *it does work*?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Element.classList.toggle`, and as a boolean (`toggle` takes an optional second argument that basically says `add` if true, and `remove` if false), pass `currentlyIteratedItem === clickedItem`:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  const list = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
  for (const listItem of list) {
    listItem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
      const clickedItem = e.target;
      for (const currentlyIteratedItem of list) {
        currentlyIteratedItem.classList.toggle('clicked', currentlyIteratedItem === clickedItem);
      }
    })
  }
});
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const mapping = arr.map(item => `<li class="item">${item}</li>`);
document.querySelector('.items').innerHTML = mapping.join(' ');
```

```css
.clicked {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <ul class="items">
  </ul>
</div>
```