# Toggle a CSS code On/Off depending if an element is visible or not

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am in the process of creating a top bar with HTML and CSS. I've added CSS to make the code responsive with a flex element. It looks like this:

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 820px) {
  nav.container {
    flex-grow: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="topbar">

  <nav class="container">
    <div class="text1">Text</div>
  </nav>

  <nav class="container">
    <div class="text2">Text2</div>
  </nav>

  <nav class="container">
    <div class="text3">Text3</div>
  </nav>

  <nav class="container">
    <div class="text4">Text4</div>
    <div class="text5">Text5</div>
    <!--This is triggered by an external 
             Javascript code, it is sometimes visible and sometimes not visible. -->
  </nav>

</div>
```

The only thing I'm missing right now is a code, that disables the CSS code above when the div (Text5) is not visible.

Edit: I will need a function, that checks if the provided "div with the class text5" has "display: none;" and then toggles the CSS code i've provided off.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I toggle an element's class in pure JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880890/how-do-i-toggle-an-elements-class-in-pure-javascript)

Comment: I am a Javascript novice so I cant really start anything with the question you've provided me with. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Could you share the js code so we can see how you hide it and maybe modify your js to affect the css ? It's easier to do if we know what triggers your div to get the display:none property

Comment: I dont have access to the javascript code because my website is based on a shop system...(shopware 5). But i still have the ability to add external javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your edit you will have to do something like this.

```
//This function returns true if the display of all divs with classOfTheDiv is none
function checkIfIsHidden(classOfTheDiv){
     let divs =  document.getElementsByClass(idOfTheDiv);
     var allHidden = true;
     divs.forEach((div)=>{
         if(!(div.style.display === "none")){
         allHidden = false;
         }
     })
return allHidden;
}
//This function will activate the media query only if "text5" is not display none
function activateMediaQuery(){
    let mediaMatch = window.matchMedia("screen and (max-width: 820px)")
    if(!checkIfIsHidden("text5")){    
        mediaMatch.addListener(mediaQueryGenerator)
    }else{
        mediaMatch.removeListener(mediaQueryGenerator)
    }
}
//This function generates the media query. You will no longer need the css, so disable it. 
function mediaQueryGenerator(mediaMatch){
    if(mediaMatch.matches){
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.container');
        elements.forEach((element)=>{
            element.style.flexGrow = "3";
        })
    }
}
```

This is not the simplest nor the shortest way to do it, but IMO it's the easiest to understand. You will have to call the `activateMediaQuery()` function on the main thread of your JS code, and disable or comment your current media query. Edit: I've just noticed you don't have any ID. Im gonna assume you want all the divs with the same class ("text5") to get checked.

Comment: The `<div>` has no `id` so this will fail.

Comment: @Michael ups my bad, editing.

Comment: @Michael what do you think about it now?

Comment: Not tested, but should work.

Comment: Thank you for replying, I will test it and give a feedback. :)