# Hide elements the correct way

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using JavaScript to hide and show some elements onclick events

Using this code

```
function showPreOne() {
    document.getElementById('SecandModalFilter').classList.add('d-none');
    document.getElementById('FirstModalFilters').classList.add('d-none');
    document.getElementById('colocation').classList.add('d-none');
    document.getElementById('coloc-row').classList.add('d-none');
    document.getElementById('preFirstModalFilter').classList.remove('d-none');
    document.getElementById('FirstModalFiltersa').classList.add('d-none');
}
```

I don't think this is the correct way! ? specially if I have a very large page with a lot of tabs and elements ?

Thank you

Comment: This answer may help tidy it up a little bit: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880890/how-do-i-toggle-an-elements-class-in-pure-javascript

Comment: Why don't you think this is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a class on all the element that can be hidden (I assume you are handling a tab system), and just show the one you want to be visible:

```js
function showPreOne() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.tab').forEach(elt => elt.classList.add('d-none'))
    document.querySelector('#SecandModalFilter').classList.remove('d-none');
}
```

Otherwise, your current method is not wrong per-say.

Answer (score 2):

If the class is `display: none`, there's nothing wrong with that approach. Although the code would be more maintainable if you managed the add/remove elements with arrays of ids instead of doing it line by line.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach can be a bit better, if you are showing/hiding elements I suggest you to use the toggle functionnality.
This way you can use only one function that will manage your click event and hide/show your elements, just be sure that the initial state (d-none class present or not) is correct :

```
function showHide() {
    document.getElementById('SecandModalFilter').classList.toggle('d-none');
    document.getElementById('FirstModalFilters').classList.toggle('d-none');
    document.getElementById('colocation').classList.toggle('d-none');
    document.getElementById('coloc-row').classList.toggle('d-none');
    document.getElementById('preFirstModalFilter').classList.toggle('d-none');
    document.getElementById('FirstModalFiltersa').classList.toggle('d-none');
}
```

More informations here [Toggle specification](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_class.asp)