Square Color Not Changing
I made tiles of square with HTML,CSS, and Javascript and I'm trying make clickable squares and the color of the square must change to the #e3ff17 simultaneously. If I click that same square, the color must go back to normal.
I've tried multiple ways, but none of them worked. I cannot even click on it. How do I make the tiles or squares clickable and change the color, and switch the color back to original when I click it again? Here is my code:"


function changeBackgroundColor(event) {
  var color = "#eaef44";
  event.style.changeBackgroundColor = color;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  place-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /*Add this line*/
}

#cont {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.square {
  margin: .5px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 0;
}
<div class="square" id="D14" style="background-color: #eee1c6;" onclick="changeColor()"></div>
<div class="square" id="E14" style="background-color: #00a881;"></div>
<div class="square" id="F14" style="background-color: #eee1c6;"></div>
<div class="square" id="G14" style="background-color: #00a881;"></div>
<div class="square" id="H14" style="background-color: #eee1c6;"></div>
<div class="square" id="I14" style="background-color: #00a881;"></div>
<div class="square" id="J14" style="background-color: #eee1c6;"></div>
<div class="square" id="K14" style="background-color: #00a881;"></div>




event.style.changeBackgroundColor makes very little sense. style is an attribute of a DOM element, not an event.  And the style name is just backgroundColor, it doesn't have change in it. It should be event.target.style.backgroundColor

You're also missing the event argument in onchange="changeColor()"

even so, it makes more sense to toggle classes than swap the background colors directly. - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18880890/how-do-i-toggle-an-elements-class-in-pure-javascript

I think there is a problem with the event part

You made a bunch of small mistakes:

The function name is changeBackgroundColor(), but you're calling changeColor() in the onclick attribute. These need to be consistent.
You didn't pass event as an argument when calling the function.
The name of the style is backgroundColor, not changeBackgroundColor.
style is a property of event.target, not event.

To switch it back, you can save the original background color in a data attribute.


function changeColor(event) {
  const t = event.target;
  var color = "#eaef44";
  if (t.dataset.color) {
    t.style.backgroundColor = t.dataset.color;
    t.dataset.color = '';
  } else {
    t.dataset.color = t.style.backgroundColor;
    t.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  place-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  /*Add this line*/
}

#cont {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
}

.square {
  margin: .5px;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  list-style: none;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  font-size: 0;
}
<div class="square" id="D14" style="background-color: #eee1c6;" onclick="changeColor(event)"></div>
<div class="square" id="E14" style="background-color: #00a881;"></div>
<div class="square" id="F14" style="background-color: #eee1c6;"></div>
<div class="square" id="G14" style="background-color: #00a881;"></div>
<div class="square" id="H14" style="background-color: #eee1c6;"></div>
<div class="square" id="I14" style="background-color: #00a881;"></div>
<div class="square" id="J14" style="background-color: #eee1c6;"></div>
<div class="square" id="K14" style="background-color: #00a881;"></div>




It worked as you said. When I clicked for the first time the color changed, then I clicked for the second time, the tile went back to the original color, but when I clicked for the THIRD time, it wasn't responding.                                                                             So I had to refresh the browser for the tile to be clickable again.                             How do I make it clickable for unlimited times?

It works for every time, I don't know why it's not working for you.

Did you forget t.dataset.color = '';? I had that problem until I put that in.

I didn't forget it, but I typed the color '#eee1c6'; which I wasn't supposed to do.  Now it works! Thanks for your help!~
